# how to configure network Authentication?

Tags: server, networking, ldap, openldap

i would like to configure network authentication can any one help me to configue ldap,ACL,kerberos step by step

Answer (score 1):

There is some Ubuntu Community Documentation on the topics you mentioned:

- [OpenLDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer)
- [ACL or Access Control Lists](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HelpOnAccessControlLists)
- [Kerberos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos)

Hopefully these will help.